# Sinon doesn't stub getter of react component

Tags: reactjs, tdd, sinon, enzyme, stubbing

Sinon doesn't stub getter of react component.

In my react component:

```
get statusTitle() {
  return 'Status Title'
}
```

I do following:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent />)
const stubStatusTitle = stub(wrapper, 'statusTitle').get(() => 'test')
```

But this doesn't work. Anyway it returns me 'Status Title'.
Even 
`const stubStatusTitle = stub(wrapper.instance(), 'statusTitle').get(() => 'test')` doesn't work.

Has someone encountered this?

Thanks!

Comment: If I remember correctly, `instance` function  is available only when you use `mount`

Comment: @ezelen would you mind acting on the information provided? you either comment, upvote or do something to say if the answer given was sufficeint or not. if you don't people will refrain from answering beginners on StackOverflow such as yourself, as using time on answering them becomes fruitless and pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the instance is created outside of your control. As the JSX expression `<SomeComponent />` is equivalent of the javascript expression `React.createElement(SomeComponent, null)`, you can see that the point where the instance is created from the `SomeComponent` function/class is hidden inside of React.

But all hope is not lost - this is javascript, after all :-)

What we can do is do the stubbing on the prototype chain, instead of on the instance itself:

```
class MyComponent {
    get foo() {
        return 123;
    }
}

const obj = new MyComponent;
console.log( obj.foo); // => '123'

Object.defineProperty(MyComponent.prototype, 'foo', {get: ()=>42})
console.log( obj.foo); // => '42'
```

Using this, and knowing that the instance is created from the `SomeComponent` class, we can modify the `getStatus` property on the prototype instead of on the instance:

```
const stubStatusTitle = stub(SomeComponent.prototype, 
                             'statusTitle')
                        .get(() => 'test');
```

This should hopefully do what you intended, as the component mounted by Enzyme should now output 'test' from its property.

Comment: But what about functional components?

Comment: What about them? You do not say what information is missing from the answer. Post a new question and link to it from here.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Well, I was asking how would you go about stubbing components that do not have `prototype`, like functional components?

Comment: If you have a standalone function, then there is nothing to stub, is there? You need an injection point where you can inject a replacement. Expose a way of doing so. Check this article I wrote for some of the many ways: https://sinonjs.org/how-to/typescript-swc/